# Can you use use Loop-Cut tool with ngons?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I have a loop cut(no face,vertices only) on one ngon cap of a cylinder. I would like to cut the opposing cap with this shape. I cant use mirror here because there are other shapes on the cap I dont want to copy. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you upload the .blend to pasteAll.org and paste the link here it will be easier to help since guessing at your setup makes an answer a bit difficult.  It does sound like the Knife Project tool is what you need though.

Comment: Knife project seems buggy with ngons even in the lastest version. I cut holes in a cylinder using KP and several curves. Worked on one face but not fully on the other. one of the curves didnt cut. File at http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33204

Comment: I think you could make it easier by insetting the ngons so you have a ring of quads around them, so the loop cut can turn the corner and make it easier to join afterwards. If you're subsurfing this will make your corners cleaner, if not you can limited dissolve them away again later.

Comment: thanks starweaver. That makes the most sense so far. ngons are easier to work with but since the final project should have as few as possible I should start learning to create quads. even if it mean trickier selection

Answer (score 6):

Loop cut intentionally only cuts quads.

To cut across ngons you can:

- Use the knife tool to cut up the face how you like.
- Select 2 vertices and run join (Jkey).

---

*Note, we have support for ths in the code, but after discussion with users, disabled it - see `BMW_EDGERING_NGON`*
See:
http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/2012-March/043815.html

Answer (score 5):

I would use the kinfe tool <kbd>K</kbd> to make the cut.

[image]

You can make complex cuts if you desire, by left clicking:

[image]

Comment: What if I need to make a complex cut? like a curved shape?

Comment: You can add any number of verts within the existing face using the knife tool. You can add one edge and then subdivide it etc. Once you have the edge in place you can use other tools to place them in a nice curve etc.