# Why can't I loop cut this face?

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, workflow, faces

everybody.

I'm new to blender and I think I got one of those beginner problems. I am trying to make a goat and one of the faces won't let me loop cut it. It just skips the face.

[image]

I would be glad if you could help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19596/can-you-use-use-loop-cut-tool-with-ngons

Answer (score -1):

that face is a N-gon. A N-gon is a face which the number of edges is different from 4. The loopcut doesn't work there as you want, because there are several paths that it could do. Consider delete that face and rebuild just with quadrilateral faces (quad-faces). You might consider to learn a bit of topology and retopology techniques, where they take this issue all the time, and teach cool ways to solve this while modelling
.

Comment: don't forget also to "remove doubles", and keep your "normals consistent". ;)

Comment: If you're willing to improve your answer, draw the correct topology over his screenshot. That would be helpful.