# Loop Cut and Subdivision isn't working on some faces

Tags: modeling, faces, bevel

After applying bevel tool I can't cut adjacent faces with loop tool, and subdivision (what I actually want to do with the face) doesn't work either. How can I fix this? Or maybe there is a workaround?

[image: lc problem]

Comment: When a face has more than four vertices, loop tool is not going to work https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19596/can-you-use-use-loop-cut-tool-with-ngons

Answer (score 0):

I am still a relatively new user myself and with limited information, it's hard to know for sure, but I have a few suggestions if still stuck.

1. Check to see if all faces are quads. In Edit mode, click on the 'Section' tab and scroll down to Select All by Trait', and then select 'Faces by Sides'. I do not think you will be able to make a loop cut without it being a quad-at least that was the case for me.
2. Maybe your clipping needs adjusting? On the viewport do shortcut 'N' on the Workspace and try adjusting the 'Clip Start' or 'End'. I ran into problems with not being able to see knife cuts because my clipping was too small so I had to raise this and rescale my model in order to see the cuts. Maybe there is something similar like that going on for you.
3. Apply Scale. Object Mode, 'Ctrl' + 'A'. Sometimes things get out of wack when you are altering the mesh.
4. This doesn't seem to be the case for you, but I have had times when I couldn't do a loop cut when I had an extrusion going another way. Maybe you have something like that in between? In other words, you may have some internal geometry that is preventing the loop cut. So, I've fixed this by selecting the very end of the inside mesh that I don't need, pressing 'Ctrl +' until I select all the hidden mesh, and then deleting those faces or whatnot. I have not had a chance to use this, but If you can't see a mesh, then try this: in edit mode, make sure you deselect everything, then press shortcut 'Ctrl, Alt, and Shift + M, X' then select delete faces. Suggest using x-ray mode so you do not accidentally delete something you need.

I've found these things to help me when I run into similar problems. Not sure if these things will help, but figure it wouldn't hurt to try if you are still stuck since you can always save and go back!

Comment: Thank you for help. Seems like loop cut tool isn't cutting n-gon faces, same for subdividion. Gonna do some retopology.